# Print ssh and su chain

Tags: bash

**Is there a way to show the complete ssh and su chain in bash?**

For example. In Server A as user aa:

```
su - ab
ssh ba@B
su - bb
```

Thus, I would like a command that prints something like this:

```
1 bash aa in A
2 su ab in A
3 ssh ba in B
4 su bb in B
```

I tried pstree but it does not print the users and only works with the processes of the last ssh'ed server:

```
$ pstree | grep -C 5 pstree
serversshd---sshd---sshd---bash---su---bash-+-grep
     |                                       `-pstree
```

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate: [Showing a stack of ssh connections in terminal](http://superuser.com/questions/435683/showing-a-stack-of-ssh-connections-in-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can find easily (the server you come from) :

```
$ who
ba     pts/0        2012-11-14 22:47 (<A hostname>)
```

I do not think there are any readily available way to retrieve your full `bash`/`ssh`/`su` history. Here is what I would suggest to go a little further than your original `pstree`. But this is very sketchy, though.

Retrieving the sshd pid :

```
$ pstree -p | grep -B1 pstree
    |-sshd(8259)---sshd(23962)---bash(23965)-+-grep(24390)
    |                                        `-pstree(24389)
```

This allows you to find out which port on server `A` is connected to `sshd` on `B` :

```
$ lsof -i -P | grep 23962
sshd      23962        ba    3r  IPv4 36943568       TCP B:22->A:50174 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Then you could look for who is using this port on `A` :

```
$  lsof -i -P| grep 50174
ssh       19085        ab    3u  IPv4 0x81104c4d3b4ee24d      0t0  TCP A:50174->B:22 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Now you could use `19085` with pstree to figure out what has been done on `A`.